# Perform row-wise operation in datatable with multiple elements

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data table:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
DT <- data.table(ind=1:100,x=sample(100),y=sample(100),group=c(rep("A",50),rep("B",50)))
```

Now the problem I have is that I need to take every value in column "x" (that is, each given ID), and add all the existing values in column "y" to it. I also need to do it separately per column "group". Let's assume we start with ID = 1. This element has the value: x_1 = 68, and y_1 = 76. We also see y_2 = 39, y_3 = 24, etc. So what I want to compute is the sums x_1 + y_1, x_1 + y2, x_1 + y_3, etc. But not only for x_1, but also for x_2, x_3, etc. So for x_2 it would look like: x_2 + y_1, x_2 + y_2, x_2 + y_3, etc. This should also be done separately per column "group" (in this regard the dataset should simple be split by group).

Edit: Exemplary code to do this only for X_1 and group A:

```
current_X <- DT[1,x] # not needed, just to illustrate
vector_current_X <- rep(DT[1,x],nrow(DT[group == "A"]))
DT[group == "A",copy_current_X := vector_current_X]
DT[,sum_current_X_Y := copy_current_X + y]
DT
```

One apparent issue with this approach is that if it were applied to all x, then a lot of columns would be added to the final DT. So I am not sure if it is the best approach. In the end, I am just looking for the lowest sum (per element x) with each element y, and per group.

I know how to do operations per group, and I also know the lapply functions. The issue is that from my understanding, I need to include a row-wise loop. And next, the structure of the result will be different from the original data table, because we have many additional observations. I have seen before that you can save lists inside a data.table, but I am unsure if that is the best approach. My dataset is much larger, so efficiency is important.

Thanks for any hints how to approach this.

Comment: Please show your desired output. Note there is no row in the sample data where x=50 and y=52. Please check your seed and your explanation

Comment: @langtang thanks for the hint. Indeed, somehow that was not the seed I have used. I edited the text, now it should be fine. I will try to add the desired output exemplary for some elements

Comment: If `x` is a given ID, then performing arithmetic operations on it is illogical, as ID is a categorical concept. While this is just "words", there are many things in data-science-y things that can be confusing when misunderstood.

Comment: Do you want the sum of those sums for each x, resulting in 1 row per x, or do you want the individual sums, thus expanding from 100 rows to 5000 rows (50 rows for each x)?

Comment: @langtang I was looking for 50 rows for each x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
DT[, .(.BY$x+DT[group==.BY$group,y]), by=.(x,group)]
```

This returns N rows per x, where N is the size of x's group. We leverage the special (`.BY`), which is available in `j` when utilizing `by`. Basically, `.BY` is a named list, containing the values of the grouping variables. Here, I'm adding the value of x (`.BY$x`) to the vector of `y` values from the subset of `DT` where the `group` is equal to the current group value (`.BY$group`)

Output:

```
          x  group    V1
      <int> <char> <int>
   1:    68      A   144
   2:    68      A   107
   3:    68      A    92
   4:    68      A   121
   5:    68      A   160
  ---                   
4996:     4      B    25
4997:     4      B    66
4998:     4      B    83
4999:     4      B    27
5000:     4      B    68
```

You can also accomplish this via a join:

```
DT[,!c("y")][DT[, .(y,group)], on=.(group), allow.cartesian=T][, total:=x+y][order(ind)]
```

Output:

```
        ind     x  group     y total
      <int> <int> <char> <int> <int>
   1:     1    68      A    76   144
   2:     1    68      A    39   107
   3:     1    68      A    24    92
   4:     1    68      A    53   121
   5:     1    68      A    92   160
  ---                               
4996:   100     4      B    21    25
4997:   100     4      B    62    66
4998:   100     4      B    79    83
4999:   100     4      B    23    27
5000:   100     4      B    64    68
```

Comment: Excellent! One line of code. I knew it was a mistake to begin thinking about loops. Could you explain your code a bit? Never seen this `BY` syntax before.

Comment: I've added another option, which is less opaque, plus an explanation for the first approach

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the requested result requires a *cross join* where each element of `x` is combined with each element of `y` (within each `group`).

This can be accomplished easily using the `CJ()` function:

```
DT[, CJ(x, y, sorted = FALSE), by = group][, sum_x_y := x + y][]
```

> ```
>       group  x  y sum_x_y
>    1:     A 68 76     144
>    2:     A 68 39     107
>    3:     A 68 24      92
>    4:     A 68 53     121
>    5:     A 68 92     160
>   ---                    
> 4996:     B  4 21      25
> 4997:     B  4 62      66
> 4998:     B  4 79      83
> 4999:     B  4 23      27
> 5000:     B  4 64      68
> ```