# Performance issues with large panel row-wise operation in datatable

Tags: r, optimization, datatable, large-data

This is a follow-up question. I have the following panel data:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
time=rep(seq(as.Date("2001-01-31"), as.Date("2050-01-31"), by="years"))
nrOfIDs <- 10000
groupvars <- letters[1:5]
DT <- data.table(time=rep(time,nrOfIDs),
             ind=rep(1:nrOfIDs,each=length(time)),
             x=sample(nrOfIDs*length(time)),
             y=sample(nrOfIDs*length(time)),
             group=rep(groupvars,each=(nrOfIDs*length(time))/length(groupvars)))


nrow(DT) # 500000
```

What I want to do, in short, is for every ID, take every value in column "x" and add all the existing values in column "y" to it. This has to be done in the dataset separately per "group".
For instance, for x1, I need to compute x1 + y1, x1 + y2, x1 + y3, and so on. Then the same for x2, x3, x4, etc. In each case, always add all possible y-values to the respective x-value.

I received several answers on how to do this (see: [Perform row-wise operation in datatable with multiple elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72143590/perform-row-wise-operation-in-datatable-with-multiple-elements)), but they do not work on my dataset. The problem is that it blows up. Exemplary, In the above code, I use `nrOfIDs <- 10000`. This could be increased even further to get closer to my actual problem, but the code already does not work for this number. For example, using a cross-join with the following code:

```
DT[, CJ(x, y, sorted = FALSE), by = .(ind,group)]
```

gives: `Error in [.data.table(DT, , CJ(x, y, sorted = FALSE), by = .(time, group)) :  negative length vectors are not allowed`

The reason is too many rows of the result. If we use for example:

```
DT[, CJ(x, y, sorted = FALSE), by = .(group)]
```

we get: `Error in CJ(x, y, sorted = FALSE) :  Cross product of elements provided to CJ() would result in 10000000000 rows which exceeds .Machine$integer.max == 2147483647`

So this seems to be a performance problem, but not only.

In the end I am only looking for the lowest sum for each of the resulting pairs. Let's say the sums of x1 with y1 is 2, the sum of x1 with y2 is 3, etc., and all other sums are > 2. So I only needed to save the sum of x1 with y1 in this case. But to achieve this we need the intermediate results as well. So I am not sure how to do it without making the dataset so much larger.

I would be helpful for any hints. I am not sure but it seems to me that with larger datasets this can only be solved by looping the IDs?

Comment: Is it possible to call `min` over the `y` values, then add the result to `x` once? If you only want to consider a subset of the `y` column, then call `min` over each respective subset and add the results to `x` correspondingly. I don't know R and also don't quite understand your dataset, so I might be missing something here?

Comment: @mimocha thanks for the comment. Yes that would be possible, but assume the real case is not that simple. I was trying to frame the problem as simple as possible, so a solution could be created in a short time (if possible at all). The dataset is a simple panel - it has 2 variables (x and y) for individuals over time. So 3 dimensions.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Requiring all-pair computation will always lead to a combinatorial explosion. The only alternatives I can think of is to filter out unlikely `y` values (doesn't solve the issue long term), or to just use loops. Is there a specific reason why you are trying not to use loops?

Comment: Or have you considered using something like MapReduce? [This blog might be useful](https://burtmonroe.github.io/SoDA501/Materials/SplitApplyCombine_R/)

Comment: @mimocha thanks for all the hints, I will check those out. Well all combinations do not have to be saved (only the min does), but the problem is such that all combinations have to be computed unavoidedly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably missing something here, but...

```
f <- \(x, y) {sapply(as.data.table(outer(y,x,'+')), min)}
DT[, .(result = f(x, y)), by=.(group, ind)]
##     group   ind result
##  1:     a     1  24664
##  2:     a     1 453013
##  3:     a     1 124689
##  4:     a     1 436799
##  5:     a     1 332006
```

This runs in 3.9s on my machine.

Comment: @jihoward thank you very much. This is actually what I have been looking for. `outer` prevents the addition of too many rows, as it is a matrix instead. The order was a bit confusing (you use y as x in the function), but the way you state it, it is correct.